# How do I get all elements of Hashmap key and values outside while loop

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, while-loop, hashmap

I have a query where I retrieve DB values like:

```java
public HashMap<String,String> getStateCapital(String Country) {
    
    HashMap<String,String> c1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        
    String query = DB query+Country;
        
    try {
        Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,Username,Password);
        Statement st = db.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()) {
        
            c1.put("StateName",rs.getString(3));
            c1.put("CapitalCity",rs.getString(4)); 
           
            System.out.println(c1);                // First c1 output
        } 

        System.out.println(c1);                    // Second c1 output
    
    }
}
```

Here when I print the first `c1` I get `HashMap<key,value>` Output as

```
{StateName=Karnata, CapitalCity=Bengaluru}
{StateName=Kerala, CapitalCity=Thiruvananthapuram} 
{StateName=Telangana, CapitalCity=Hyderabad} 
{StateName=TamilNadu, CapitalCity=Chennai}
etc...
```

But when I print the second `c1` I get `HashMap<key,value>` Output as

```
{StateName=Karnata, CapitalCity=Bengaluru}
```

How do I retrieve all the `HashMap<key,value>` like the first `c1` Output outside while loop?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what a Map is in java. A Map maps one key to a specific value. In your case those keys are "StateName" and "CapitalCity". Your Map can only have one single value for each of those keys. You could use a multimap, but honestly this would also not be an ideal data structure to hold your data. You should really just create your own custom class (for example StateCapital) that holds the state name and capital name as properties and then return a list of that custom class.

Comment: Why I retrieve like the above method is I need to pass those as together into an rest-assured api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that `Map` is a list of entries. Each entry is composed by a `key` and a `value`.
The key inside is unique, then the value is overridden every time you put the same key.

You can resolve to create a class that represents the state.

```java
public class State {
    private String stateName;
    private String capitalCity;

    public State(String stateName, String capitalCity) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.capitalCity = capitalCity;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public String getCapitalCity() {
        return capitalCity;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "State{" +
            "stateName='" + stateName + '\'' +
            ", capitalCity='" + capitalCity + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

}
```

And you can fill a list of `State` in order to avoid overriding.

```java
public HashMap<String, String> getStateCapital(String Country) {

    List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = DB query + Country;

    try {
        Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, Username, Password);
        Statement st = db.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            states.add(new State(rs.getString(3), rs.getString(3)));
        }
        System.out.println(states);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The values are overridden with each iteration, that's why the first `println` statement correctly prints out the key and value. The `Map` only contains the last added pair as long as by definition it doesn't allow duplicate keys.

---

I recommend rather using an object encapsulating the `stateName` and `capitalCity` and adding such an object into a `List`.

```java
public class State {

    private final String name;
    private final String capitalCity

    // all-args constructor and getters
}
```

```
List<State> c1 = new ArrayList<>();

...

// in the while-loop
c1.add(new State(rs.getString(3), rs.getString(3)));
```

---

Also, it is possible to group the map-values into the `List` resulting in `Map<String, List<String>>`.

```java
Map<String, List<String>> c1 = new HashMap<>();

...

// in the while-loop
c1.computeIfAbsent("StateName", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(rs.getString(3));
c1.computeIfAbsent("CapitalCity", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(rs.getString(3));
```

An alternative solution would be using a sort of [`MultiValueMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) (from Spring framework, but feel free to search for other libraries or frameworks if they offer something similar) that is just a wrapper to the structure above: `Map<String, List<String>>`.

---

A side note: Always program against interfaces, i.e.:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();     // :)
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); // :(
```

Comment: Thanks @nikolas-charalambidis. I tried your method and the code worked for me!